# JAVA: get the creation date of a remote file via sftp

Tags: java, jsch

Please I want to get the creation date of a remote file but I don't found a method that gives this option.
I can get just the last modified date but i want to get the creation date of this file:

here is my code:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class mytest {


    public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        //===============================================================
        String hostname = "10.10.11.19";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "passwword";
        String remoteFile = "/opt/test_pyt/teeeeeeest.txt"
        String copyTo = "/home/desk/Desktop";
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        System.out.println("Trying to connect.....");
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            //get date of file=========================================   
            String lastModif = sftpChannel.lstat(remoteFile).getMtimeString();

            //I want to get creation date =============================
            creation_date= ???????????;

          //==============================================
                sftpChannel.get(remoteFile, copyTo);
                sftpChannel.exit();
                session.disconnect();


        } catch (JSchException e) {
        } catch (SftpException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Not all filesystems record a file's creation time. There may be no value to get.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do this with jsch:

```
Vector vec = channel.ls("File Name");
// Assumption only no duplicate file names on server
if (vec != null && vec.size() == 1) {
        LsEntry details = (LsEntry) vec.get(0);
        SftpATTRS attrs = details.getAttrs();

        int t = attrs.getMTime();
        java.utl.Date modTime = new Date(t * 1000L);

}
```

Comment: works not with windos ssh

Answer (score 2):

The [SFTP standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-02) doesn't include a way of getting a file's created date.  You're out of luck, sorry.

Comment: Probably start a shell, `ls -l` the file and read the output into a date.

Comment: @PeterMmm Unix filesystems don't normally record the file creation time. mtime is the last time the file contents changed, and ctime is the last time the inode data changed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by running linux command `stat --printf="%y\n" ${file}` via sshChannel.

First a universal method to run command and return the system output:

```
String runCommand(String command) {
        Session session = connect(details); // change to your connection here
        ChannelExec execChannel = null;
        try {
            execChannel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
            execChannel.setCommand(command);
            InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader( execChannel.getInputStream() );
            execChannel.setErrStream( System.err, true );
            execChannel.connect();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            char[] buffer = new char[128];
            int read;
            while ( ( read = stream.read( buffer, 0, buffer.length ) ) >= 0 ) {
                output.append( buffer, 0, read );
            }
            stream.close();
            new Await()
                    .waitUntil(execChannel, Channel::isClosed, 10000); //it's my implementation; you can just wait in loop until it's closed
            execChannel.disconnect();
            return output.toString();
        } catch (JSchException | IOException e) {
            handleException(e);
            return "Command execution failed";
        } finally {
            cleanup(execChannel, session);
        }
    }
```

and then:

`sshClient.runCommand("stat --printf=\"%y\\n\" /path/to/your/file-or-folder")`

It will return a string in following format:

> 2020-11-11 14:32:36.936232330 +0530

So it's quite easy to parse it to the some Data type.